# Remove the image from a imageview Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to make an `ImageView` that holds a gallery of images. By touching the user request to load the next image. If the next image isn't found in the server or takes time to load I need the old image to be empty.

`setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` don't work for me because when invisible/gone I stop the `onTouch()` detecting (and the user is locked to current image).

How can I make the `ImageView` to load a empty bitmap or clear (remove) current bitmap?

Comment: ImageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent); from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859212/how-to-clear-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: choose corect answer  pls

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you, it helps others..

Answer (score 460):

I always use

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: strange! its not working. In fact setImageResouce(0) and setBackground(null) is also not working. Any idea what could be the reason or any trick to clear the cache or something.

Comment: Are you calling this from the main (UI) Thread?

Comment: If an image is not loaded into imageView and still one tries to clear it, the program stops unexpectedly. Is there a way to tackle this ?

Comment: @Krithi07 Check for image resource before clearing it.

Comment: @RamKr , what are you writing while you are setting ? 

If you use imageview.setBackgroundResource() and you should use image.setBackgroundResource(0), If you use imageView.setImageDrawable() than you should use imageView.setImageDrawable(null).

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
imageView.setImageResource(0);
```

This will set the image view to use no resource.

Comment: not working for me =( after call imageView.setImageResource(0) it still shows the old picture

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Well it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks, finally view.setImageDrawable(null) worked as i wanted

Comment: @ChyBy If you use the support library, you get `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` , which supports `setImageResource(0)` on all devices.

Answer (score 15):

From what I've noticed, the "working" or not of certain method when clearing image depends on the method used to populate ImageView.

So if you set `img.setImageBitmap(bmp)` then to clear you should use `img.setImageBitmap(null)`.
When you `img.setImageResource(resId)` then to clear you should use `img.setImageResouce(0)`.
Etc.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly imageView.setImageResource(0) works. It has never failed for me and I have used it many times.

setImageResource is usually passed the reference R.drawable,(the reference for the picture), which is stored as an int, but displayed in the R.java class as a hex value, 0xf2fs... So assuming this reference exist it will show a picture, if you later pass that same imageview a reference which does not exist the old picture will no longer show. So, if you pass it 0, or 5 or an int which does not match a resource referenced in your R.java class it will remove the picture completely from the src of the imageView. So if you are passing 0 to the old reference of the imageView.

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(0)` didn't work for me on a Samsung S5 running 4.4.2. However `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);` works.

Comment: @rlay3 If you use the support library, you get `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` , which supports `setImageResource(0)` on all devices.