# An issue with my CustomListAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listadapter

the thing is in my customlistadapter it will show a text and a picture in six rows. But in the last row, It will only show the text, not the picture. When I put 0 instead of the picture, they show the default pic, but I dont want to have any pic there. How to do it? Any tips would be really valuable thank you.

In this line:

```
-> pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Egendefinert", 0));
```

ListAdapterClass

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pilstyper> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(velgDinPromille.this, R.layout.activity_item_view, pilsTyper);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_item_view, parent, false);
        }

        // finn pilstype som du skal jobbe med
        Pilstyper nyPils = pilsTyper.get(position);

        // ImageView
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.lettol);
        imageView.setImageResource(nyPils.getIkonId());

        // Tekst
        TextView tekst = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tekst_pils);
        tekst.setText(nyPils.getTekst());

        return itemView;
    }
} 

private void pilsTyperList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Øl", R.drawable.ol));
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Cider og rusbrus", R.drawable.cider));
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Vin", R.drawable.vin));
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Sterkvin", R.drawable.portvin2));
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Brennevin/Drinker", R.drawable.drink2));
    pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Egendefinert", 0));
}
```

Comment: have you tried `imgView.setImageDrawable(null);` or `imgView.setImageResource(0);`?

Comment: is `Pilstyper` your own class? if so, you can handle `0` value there

Comment: nope, I am going to try this now, thanks

Comment: Try to replace this line: pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Egendefinert", 0)); With this: pilsTyper.add(new Pilstyper("Egendefinert", R.drawable.someimagename));

Comment: @shayan, if I use that then all items get the same pic.
haresh, but I dnt want any pic there. only text
nikis, how can I do that ?

Comment: you must handle on your code, if key is equal to 0 then set your image to null, else set image to keyId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide the ImageView when the icon id is 0. Try this:

```
if (nyPils.getIkonId() == 0) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE
} else {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.setImageResource(nyPils.getIkonId());
}
```

Comment: sometimes we think so complicated, that we forget that we can write code in this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No u have to give image id, You have not any other option.

Comment: I think it's wrong because you can set your image to null, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859212/how-to-clear-an-imageview-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643432/remove-the-image-from-a-imageview-android