# How to clear ImageView correctly?

Tags: android, imageview

For example, in my Activity I have such code (I skip the initialization of variables):

```
ImageView iview; //some ImageView
Bitmap b; //some Bitmap
iview.setImageBitmap(b);
```

**Question is** - how to clear iview resources correctly (with or without destroying view) ? Would ImageView free it's resources (used in native code) after `b.recycle()`?

I suppose, that ImageView **doesn't** just free it resources after Activity `onStop` (or `onDestroy`).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
imgview.setImageResource(0);
```

or

```
imgview.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: `imgview.setImageResource(0)`isn't working (not cleared my image from image view) setting null do working

Comment: Only works if used with uri or resource:
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        if (mUri != null || mResource != resId) {
    ...
}

Comment: setImageResource has side effects in earlier versions

Answer (score 5):

no you need to unbindDrawables, you can do it by setting `iview.setImageDrawable(null);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use frequently it works:

```
imageView.setImageResource(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewToUse.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

- I think using setImageResource with a color identifier will give you crashing issues on Android 2.2.1, make sure to test it.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing is working for you try setting the background color of view to layout color.if my layout color is white u can do like this:

```
 edit_countflag.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
//then set the image
 edit_countflag.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_id);
```