# How to set the image from drawable dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I am storing my project related images in drawable folder. Also I am storing the image names in string variable and dynamically I am trying to set those images to the imageview. But the image is not displaying. Please help me in this regard.

My Code:

```
int res = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setImageResource(res);
```

In the above code "imagename" is the string variable which contains the image name.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try this:

```
String uri = "@drawable/myresource";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```

Comment: hi i tried your code it is showing the error as android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 at line Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource); plz help me

Comment: You need to change the uri for your image name. Like "@drawable/MYIMAGENAME.extension"

Comment: image_url contains the image name as "image.png"

Comment: image_url should contain "@drawable/image.png"

Comment: It worked for me without png extension, with extension it was giving me error. So you can try without extension

Comment: working without giving extension(.png). with extension its giving error

Comment: Without image extension its working good.Please remove the image extension from your code. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Why the extension is still in the comments? I lost time 'till I got it to work by removing the extension. Even though I upvoted your answer, please edit it. Happy Pi-day :)

Comment: This is causing `FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a xxxxx byte...` on Android 5.0.x

Comment: I was too getting #0x0 problem. when I initialized imageResource  before "int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());" it was solved.

Comment: I could load an SVG XML file from drawable folder to image view using this method.

Answer (score 44):

Here i am setting the `frnd_inactive` image from `drawable` to the image

```
 imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frnd_inactive));
```

Comment: getDrawable(int) is deprecated. You should use getDrawable(int, Theme) instead.

Answer (score 43):

```
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

Comment: plus because of simplicity of this answer

Comment: how is that dynamic? the file name looks static here.

Answer (score 23):

Try this **Dynamic code**

```
String fnm = "cat"; //  this is image file name
String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+fnm , null, null);
System.out.println("IMG ID :: "+imgId);
System.out.println("PACKAGE_NAME :: "+PACKAGE_NAME);
//    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId);
your_image_view.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgId));
```

In above code you will need Image-file-Name and Image-View object **which both you are having**.

Comment: Thank you very much...this code is working perfect and you save my lot of time.

Comment: Thanks. This one worked great for me: int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+fnm , null, null);

Comment: thank you very much. after 3 hours work  your code fixed my error.

Answer (score 8):

See below code this is working for me

```
iv.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(
                "imagename", "drawable", "com.package.application"));
```

Comment: used context.getPackageName() for the package name

Answer (score 8):

set in `ImageView` like this : `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)`

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (dont use the extension of the image, just the name):

```
String imagename = "myImage";
int res = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setImageResource(res);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

if you have image in drawable folder then use

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageView)
```

if you have uri and want to display it in imageView then use

```
imageView.setImageUri("uri")
```

if you have bitmap and want to display it in imageView then use

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

note:- 1. `imageView.setImageDrawable()` is now deprecated in java
2. If image uri is from firebase or from any other online link then use

```
    Picasso.get()
    .load("uri")
    .into(imageView)
```

(https://github.com/square/picasso)

or use

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load("uri")
            .into(imageView)
```

(https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the best way that **works in every phone at today**. Most of those answer are deprecated or need an API >= 19 or 22.
You can use the fragment code or the activity code depends what you need.

**Fragment**

```
//setting the bitmap from the drawable folder
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);

//set the image to the imageView
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Activity**

```
//setting the bitmap from the drawable folder
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);

//set the image to the imageView
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picname);
```

Answer (score 3):

`getDrawable()` is deprecated, so try this

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fileName)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. To add, if you need to clear the ImageView, just do: `imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243184/1657502

Answer (score 2):

First of let's your image name is **myimage**. So what you have to do is that go to Drawable and save the image name **myimage**.

Now assume you know only image name and you need to access it. Use below snippet to access it,

what you did is correct , ensure you saved image name you are going to use inside coding.

```
public static int getResourceId(Context context, String name, String resourceType) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(toResourceString(name), resourceType, context.getPackageName());
}

private static String toResourceString(String name) {
    return name.replace("(", "")
               .replace(")", "")
               .replace(" ", "_")
               .replace("-", "_")
               .replace("'", "")
               .replace("&", "")
               .toLowerCase();
}
```

In addition to it you should ensure that there is no empty spaces and case sensitives

Answer (score 2):

As of API 22, `getResources().getDrawable()` is deprecated (see also [Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)). Here is a new way to set the image resource dynamically:

```
String resourceId = "@drawable/myResourceName"; // where myResourceName is the name of your resource file, minus the file extension
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceId, null, getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, imageResource); // For API 21+, gets a drawable styled for theme of passed Context
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: and getIdentifier is also not recommended to use nowadays

Answer (score 2):

***getDrawable() is deprecated.*
now you can use**

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.msg_status_client_read))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in **Kotlin**, inside a loop `i`:

Code reused from [rfsbraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514802/rfsbraz) 's answer

```
    val uri = "@drawable/pic_top${i+1}"
    val imageResource = activity.resources.getIdentifier(uri, null, activity.packageName)

    val res = activity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
    holder.view.imgDigit.setImageDrawable(res)
```

Comment: What should be the activity?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] phptr=new int[5];
```

adding image pointer to array

```
for(int lv=0;lv<3;lv++)
    {
        String id="a"+String.valueOf(lv+1);
        phptr[lv]= getResources().getIdentifier(id, "drawable", getPackageName());
    }

for(int loopvariable=0;loopvariable<3;loopvariable++) 
    {
        et[loopvariable] = findViewById(p[loopvariable]);
    }



for(int lv=0;lv<3;lv++)
    {
        et[k].setImageResource(phptr[k]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
final R.drawable drawableResources = new R.drawable(); 
final Class<R.drawable> c = R.drawable.class;
final Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
for (int i=0; i < fields.length;i++) 
{
     resourceId[i] = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);  
    /* till here you get all the images into the int array resourceId.*/
}
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
if(your condition)
{
   imageview.setImageResource(resourceId[any]);
}
```

Comment: resourceId[i] = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);
getting error in this line

                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field