# Change imageview's image from Bitmap object

Tags: java, android

```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

That is my imageView. When I try to change the image of it like this:

```
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.com_facebook_top_button);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

the imageview seems to be invisible. The ic_launcher image disappears and the new image is not being shown.

Comment: have you do findViewById of imageView ?

Comment: imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: I think there is some issue with your image `com_facebook_top_button`. Try `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: i didn't try but please try with doing imageView1.setimageDrawable(imageDrawable) or imageview.setimageresource(resource)

Comment: Didn't work. Even changing the image doesn't work.

Comment: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null   -   in LogCat

Comment: @Mitul The problem is I don't want to save my Bitmap object to a file.

Comment: convert bitmap to drawable and then set it using imageDrawable

Comment: @user3367856 Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android