# Need Integer resource id of drawable resources dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, android-resources

I need to set the notification image icon dynamically , whose name is passed to my class dynamically.
For that , I need to set the builder.setSmallIcon(int res_id). I googled it , but people have used the example of setDrawableImage()
I have seen this post , and accordingly implemented in my code.

```
   //blah blah lines of code
   String uri = "@drawable/a";
   int imageResource = con.getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null, con.getPackageName());
   Drawable res = con.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
   builder.setSmallIcon(res);
   //blah blah code lines
```

Of course, this shows error because setSmallIcon() requires integer to be passed to it. con is the context passed to my constructor.
I have seen [How to set the image from drawable dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course, this shows error because setSmallIcon() requires integer to be passed to it.

You already have the desired integer. You named it `imageResource`. Pass `imageResource` to `setSmallIcon()`.