# Why is the content of the ImageView empty on my real phone?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I try to set a drawable into an ImageView. The source depends on the two digit day-num in month (stored in `today`). My API-Level is 17 (The Fairphone 1).

On the virtual devices I can see the picture. But when I install the app on my real phone, the ImageBox is there but empty (white).

This is the code where I set the Image:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.startImg);
String uri = "s_"+Integer.parseInt(today);
int imageResource = getBaseContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

This is my Layout-File:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="Bild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/startImg" />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/DatesGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LogCat says nothing.

But I checked the App on a Phone on API-Level 22 (The Fairphone 2). Now the app crashes because of a wrong `imageResource`.

Question: Why can I see the picture in my Virtual Devices but not on my real device?

Comment: what is the logcat saying?

Comment: I added your requested and more info in my question.

Comment: i am not sure please try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11737758/3790150

Comment: `String uri = "s_"+Integer.parseInt(today);`. Well what would become the value of `uri`? Why didnt you tell? How can we know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all for your hints. I could solve the issue now.

There was a storage allocation error which was only debuggable on a different API-Level (22). The Level 17 has given no errors. I scaled the Images down now. This explains also why it works on the virtual devices with different storage-settings.