# Get image from drawable dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on a barcode reader app and I want to show product image when the barcode read, so I renamed photos with product barcode numbers and put drawables folder. Photo name is for ex 1234567, try to retrieve with barcodeNo. But I got error on barcodeNo. How can i do this ?

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.barcodeNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

just pass your code in getImage method to findout your image from drawable folder.

```
iv.setImageResource(getImage(barcodeNo));

public int getImage(String imageName) {

     int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

     return drawableResourceId;
}
```

Comment: is this helpful ?

Comment: I add 'a' character beginning of each photo

Comment: can i show your drawable folder's Images Screenshots ?

Comment: I try to change a123456789 to a8690504017516

Comment: I solved the problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 1):

```
String uri = "@drawable/myresource";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
OR
imageview.setImageResource(imageResource)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Narendra Sorathiya answer is right. you have write this code for solving the `NullPointerException`, which you posted on screenshot:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setImageResource(getImage(barcodeNo));
.
.
.
.
public int getImage(String imageName) {

     int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

     return drawableResourceId;
}
```

Comment: in this prntscr.com/emwayo i show the error, that's why i posted this answer.

Comment: I solved the problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android