# How to set ImageResource dynamically?

Tags: java

```
double randomDiceNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
String imageSource = "ic_dice" + Double.toString(randomDiceNumber);
dice.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageSource);
```

What I am trying to do is set an Imageview to a different dice side depending on which number is rolled.

Comment: Or should I use a switch statement in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the image from drawable dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737607/how-to-set-the-image-from-drawable-dynamically-in-android)

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I saw that one, but since I am new to Java I didn't manage to figure it out with that post.

Comment: @VoHoTv look at my answer maybe it's the solution you need

Answer (score 0):

```
double randomDiceNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);    
String uri = "@drawable/ic_dice" + Double.toString(randomDiceNumber); 
dice.setImageResource(
           getResources().getDrawable(
                  getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
           )
      );
```