# how to setImage to null in android when the xml has src not null?

Tags: java, android, image

I have this xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImgOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_on" />
```

I want to remove this image sometimes via code. I've seen many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859212/how-to-clear-an-imageview-in-android),
but in my case `imageButton.setBackgroundResource(0);` leaves the default image which appears in my xml layout.

How would you remove it programmatically? I heard transparent color crashes some old devices.

**update**

setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well and not null as i want it to be

Comment: did you try `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);`?

Comment: imageButton.setImageResource(0);

Comment: setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

Your setting `setBackgroundResource` that's for `android:background="@drawable/icon_on"` not for `android:src="@drawable/icon_on"` **background** and **src** both are **different** use

```
imageButton.setImageResource(0);
```

**EDIT**

```
imageButton.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well

Comment: @user1065869 use `imageButton.setImageDrawable(null);` see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `imageButton.setImageResource(0)`

Comment: setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well

Comment: are you sure it is the correct view you are seeing at screen?

Answer (score 1):

The background (backgroundresource) and foreground (src) image are two different things, thus the one does not influence the other.

Remove the foreground image using:

```
imageButton.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well. should i work as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to null imageview then you have to call `imageButton.setImageResource(0);` BackgroundResource only null that background of image.

Comment: setImageResource(0) left the xml's original src as well

Comment: no if u don't want to any image in xml then why should u give it at the time of create xml

Comment: just for design matters, to view before deploy

Comment: don't give anything in xml if u don't want any image in xml if u give anything in image resource then only pragmatically u have to remove this