# setImageResource(0) left the original xml src, and not null as i want it to

Tags: java, android

I have this xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImgOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_on" />
```

I want to remove this image sometimes via code. I've seen many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859212/how-to-clear-an-imageview-in-android),
but in my case `imageButton.setImageResource(0);` leaves the default image which appears in my xml layout.

How would you remove it programmatically? I heard transparent color crashes some old devices.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);`

Comment: i will but why setImageResource(0) doesn't work?

Comment: because it's trying to find an image resource with ID = 0; which isn't available. Have a look at R.java file and see how an ID is created for each of your resource.

Comment: i don't get it how it works for other people