# Android App gets crashed on clicking button

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

I am making a *TIC TAC TOE* game in *ANDROID STUDIO 3.1.3* using Java.
So when I am clicking  button, the apps crashes. I am not able to find the reason why this is happening. Please, help.
Code for button is as follows :

```
 public void playAgain(View view){

    gameIsActive = true;

     activePlayer = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i<gameState.length;i++){

         gameState[i] = 2;
     }

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

     for(int i =0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){

         ((ImageView)gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
     }

    }
```

XML code for button is as follows :

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="play again"/>
```

this is my first question so please don't mind my immature way of asking a questions.

Logcat Snippet is :

```
09-13 18:54:34.720 16114-16114/? I/nihal.tictacto: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-13 18:54:34.777 16114-16114/? W/nihal.tictacto: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-13 18:54:35.197 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe W/nihal.tictacto: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
09-13 18:54:35.201 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe I/chatty: uid=10088(com.nihal.tictactoe) identical 10 lines
09-13 18:54:35.202 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe W/nihal.tictacto: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
09-13 18:54:35.269 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-13 18:54:35.804 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe W/nihal.tictacto: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
09-13 18:54:35.805 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe W/nihal.tictacto: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
09-13 18:54:36.177 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
09-13 18:54:36.254 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe D/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=450, x2-x1>=495, x3-x2>=510, x3-x0<=1440 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x3-x0<=1440. 
09-13 18:54:36.255 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe D/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: vertical constraints: y3-y0>=2176, y3-y2<=750, y2-y1<=720, y1-y0<=570 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y3-y2<=750. 
09-13 18:54:36.326 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
09-13 18:54:36.327 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
09-13 18:54:36.327 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-13 18:54:36.327 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-13 18:54:36.327 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-13 18:54:36.327 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
09-13 18:54:36.337 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xce486000: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
09-13 18:54:36.369 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xce486000: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe48b1d00)
09-13 18:54:36.379 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
09-13 18:54:36.565 16114-16137/com.nihal.tictactoe D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xce486000: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe48b1d00)
09-13 18:55:33.056 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-13 18:55:33.077 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nihal.tictactoe, PID: 16114
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
        at com.nihal.tictactoe.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:115)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
09-13 18:55:33.203 16114-16114/com.nihal.tictactoe I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16114 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post the logcat snippet showing the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're casting to the wrong type of `GridView`. From your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
    cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
```

So at the top of your Java file you should see a line like this:

```
import android.widget.GridLayout;
```

Replace it with:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's the `setImageResource(0)` as usually Android doesn't assign 0 as ai drawable resource id. But a logcat snippet would me more helpful.

Comment: Not really, that's a perfectly valid way of clearing an image [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243184/469080). I think it's still too early to answer given the lack of information.

Comment: I added logcat snippet. Please, help. Thank you